# Excel: Trying to get a range of numbers to autopopulate in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Example: If Cell E2 contains the range "`E2171251-E2171375`", I want cell e3 to contain "`E2171376-E2171500`", and so on, for `100` cells. I'd rather not handjam `100+` cells of data.

I have no idea how to get this done, thanks in advance!

Comment: One way: =LET(start,2171251,delta,1+2171375-start,n,SEQUENCE(100,,start,delta),"E" & n & "-E" & n+delta-1)

Comment: Clearly no Recursive `LAMBDA()` required here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E3</kbd>

```
=LET(α, "E"&SEQUENCE(100,,TEXTAFTER(E2,"-E"),125)+{1,125},TAKE(α,,1)&"-"&TAKE(α,,-1))
```

---

Another alternative using <kbd>TEXTSPLIT()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E3</kbd>

```
=LET(α, "E"&TEXTSPLIT(E2,{"E","-"},,1)+SEQUENCE(100)*125, TAKE(α,,1)&"-"&TAKE(α,,-1))
```

---

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula (if you have Excel 365):

```
=LET(start,TEXTAFTER(C2,"-E"),
DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(1,100,0,1),LAMBDA(r,i,VSTACK(r,"E" & (i*125) + start +1 & "-E" & ((i+1)*125) + start))),1))
```

It adds a factor of 125 to the second value - and stacks the result.

[image]